# Regex to find a file in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I've never used Tcl previously, however, I need to modify a certain file for a project. I have used regex with Perl, however I'm unsure of the syntax with Tcl.

What I want to do is allow the user to execute the script and type in a file name that has to be searched. I want to search for the file once its found and do something. So far, here's my somewhat pseudo-code.

```
set file_name [lindex $argv 0]

while(true) {
if { found file } {
 puts "Found file!"
 {
 else { file not found )
 puts "File not found!"

}
```

I'm not sure how to check if the file was found or not? I get the complete filename from the user via an input ...

Comment: What do you mean by "once its found"? Do you want to loop until the file suddenly appears? Do you need to loop through subdirectories until it matches?

Comment: Carlos, sorry for the lack of information. I meant once its found in the root directory.

Comment: I know from http://stackoverflow.com/q/4187684/301832 that you're fetching the file list from somewhere remote, so solutions involving the local filesystem are not the best recommendation here. **But you should have said that in your question!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use a regular expression instead of glob patterns then periodically get a list of files (using `glob`) and search through it. Helpfully, lsearch accepts regexp syntax:

```
# get the regexp:
set file_pattern [lindex $argv 0]

# scan current directory:
while 1 {
    set files [glob -nocomplain *]
    if {[lsearch -regexp $files $file_pattern] < 0} {
        puts "file not found"
    } else {
        puts "file found"
    }
    after 1000 ;# sleep for 1 second
}
```

Note that in tcl regexp does not have a special syntax. It is simply a string.

Answer (score 3):

Are you expecting the user to enter a specific filename or something with shell-style wildcards?  If the latter, you'll want to use the [`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/glob.htm) command.

Others may offer better directory polling techniques, but perhaps:

```
# a utility procedure for outputting messages
proc log {msg} {puts "[clock format [clock seconds] -format %T] - $msg"}

set file_pattern [lindex $argv 0]
log "looking for $file_pattern"
while {[llength [glob -nocomplain $file_pattern]] == 0} {
    after 30000 ;# sleep for 30 seconds
    log "still waiting"
}
log "found: [join [glob $file_pattern] ,]"
```