# Tcl + Check file existence

Tags: file, tcl, expect, file-exists

I'm trying to check if a file exists or not in Tcl, but I can't seem to get a true result. Even though I know it is present.

```
while {true} {

    if { [file exists $file_name] == 1} {               
        exp_send "copy file.txt destination \r"
        puts " File copied!"
    }

    puts "File Not copied"

    }
```

I always execute the File not copied line. I did a put for `[file exists $file_name]` and I always end up with 0. But I know for a fact that the file exists in the current directory. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

An alternative method that I'm trying to pursue, is that when I do a `dir` using the tcl script. I will get an output of all the files in the directory. I just need to match my file with the list outputted and satisfy the `if` when a match was found ...

I'm executing the script from Location A, but using the script to telnet to Location B. When I do a file exists, it checks Location A itself. This is my problem ... since I need to be searching in Location B ...

Comment: Then you need to issue ssh/ftp/whatever_protocol commands to query the remote directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `file exists` command always works with local filesystems. If you want to check whether a remote system has a file, you'll have to `exp_send` it some instructions to do the check for you. Unfortunately, I can't quite tell what you're talking to from your description, so I can't actually advise how to do it.

And you want a `break` after that `puts "File copied"` line otherwise it will all go round the loop again. You probably don't want that!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Donal. About the code, I just wrote some rough pseudo code to just suggest what I'm saying. I'll look into both these methods you've suggested ..

Answer (score 0):

Donal reasonably mentioned **exp_send** as a vehicle to access a remote filesystem.  If this is an FTP context, though, I prefer a (pure-Tcl-without-Expect) solution based on Tcl's FTP library; I find this more portable, understandable, and concise.